# Getting value undefined for id attribute for dynamically generated table rows in tbody

Tags: jquery, html

I'm dynamically generating table rows on clicking add row and deleting generated rows on clicking delete rows.
When I'm using jquery to get id attribute value then getting only value of first row and for other dynamically generated rows getting undefined.

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
           {
               $('#add').click(function()
           {
               var id=parseInt($('#main tbody tr:last').attr('id'))+1;
               $('#main > tbody:last').append("<tr class=\"edit_tr\" id=\""+id+"\" ><td>"+id+"</td><td><textarea class=\"editbox\" id=\"parti_input_"+id+"\" rows=\"1\" cols=\"50\"></textarea></td><td><input type=\"text\" class=\"editbox qty\" id=\"qty_input_"+id+"\" /></td><td><input type=\"text\" class=\"editbox rs\" id=\"amountrs_input_"+id+"\" /></td><td><input type=\"text\" class=\"editbox p\" id=\"amountp_input_"+id+"\" /></td><td id=\"netamountrs_"+id+"\" ></td><td id=\"netamountp_"+id+"\"></td></tr>");

               });


           $('#del').click(function()
           {
               $('#main tbody tr:last').remove();

           }
           );

          $('#cal').click(function()
      {
          var c=$('#main tbody tr').length;
          var i;
          for(i=0;i<c;i++)
          {
              var d=$('#main tbody tr').val();
              document.write(d);
          }
          alert(c);
      });

           });
```

**HTML:**

```
<table width="800" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;" id="main">
 <tbody><tr class="edit_tr" id="1"><td>1</td><td><textarea class="editbox part" id="parti_input_1" rows="1" cols="50"></textarea></td><td><input type="text" class="editbox qty" id="qty_input_1" /></td><td><input type="text" class="editbox rs" id="amountrs_input_1" /></td><td><input type="text" class="editbox p" id="amountp_input_1" /></td><td id="netamountrs_1"></td><td id="netamountp_1"></td></tr></tbody>
   </table>
            <p id="cal">calculate</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will not fetch an ID if you dynamicly add it and it starts with a number. An object in HTML 4 can not start with a number.

Therefor you need to do create a `data-id=""` and then use `.data("id")`.

HTML:

```
<table width="800" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;" id="main">
<tbody><tr class="edit_tr" data-id="1"><td>1</td><td><textarea class="editbox part" id="parti_input_1" rows="1" cols="50"></textarea></td><td><input type="text" class="editbox qty" id="qty_input_1" /></td><td><input type="text" class="editbox rs" id="amountrs_input_1" /></td><td><input type="text" class="editbox p" id="amountp_input_1" /></td><td id="netamountrs_1"></td><td id="netamountp_1"></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
        <p id="cal">calculate</p>
```

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function()
           {
               $('#add').click(function()
           {
               var id=parseInt($('#main tbody tr:last').data('id'))+1;
               $('#main > tbody:last').append("<tr class=\"edit_tr\" data-id=\""+id+"\" ><td>"+id+"</td><td><textarea class=\"editbox\" id=\"parti_input_"+id+"\" rows=\"1\" cols=\"50\"></textarea></td><td><input type=\"text\" class=\"editbox qty\" id=\"qty_input_"+id+"\" /></td><td><input type=\"text\" class=\"editbox rs\" id=\"amountrs_input_"+id+"\" /></td><td><input type=\"text\" class=\"editbox p\" id=\"amountp_input_"+id+"\" /></td><td id=\"netamountrs_"+id+"\" ></td><td id=\"netamountp_"+id+"\"></td></tr>");

               });


           $('#del').click(function()
           {
               $('#main tbody tr:last').remove();

           }
           );

          $('#cal').click(function()
      {
          var c=$('#main tbody tr').length;
          var i;
          for(i=0;i<c;i++)
          {
              var d=$('#main tbody tr').val();
              document.write(d);
          }
          alert(c);
      });

           });
```